# R1C1 Formula result gives twice the given variable

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-r1c1-notation

I want to normalize some data and want this normalized data to change dynamically when the data changes, that's why I want to put Formula in Cells that reference different Cells. But that's not really relevant to the problem because even the simplest of Formula (shown below) doesn't work.

```vb
Public Sub Test()
    a = 15
    Cells(a, 8).FormulaR1C1Local = "=Z(" & a & ")S7"
End Sub
```

The Formula in the Cell(15,8) is `=$G30`.
I expected the following output: `=$G15`.

In many forums where people ask how to put variables in a `R1C1Formula` the answer is: `[" & a & "]`, but this gives a runtime error 1004, so I tried `()` instead and it doesn't give me any warnings, but the result is not what I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need understand the `R1C1` rules in terms of relative and absolute references.

`R15C7` is absolute: Row 15 and Column 7 = `$G$15`.

`R[15]C7` is row relative and means: The row where the formula is in plus 15 rows and Column 7. If formula is in row 15, then = `$G30`.

`RC7` means: The row where the formula is in and Column 7. If formula is in row 15, then = `$G15`.

```
Public Sub Test()
 a = 15
 Cells(a, 8).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[" & a & "]C7" '$G30
 Cells(a, 8).FormulaR1C1 = "=R" & a & "C7"   '$G$15
 Cells(a, 8).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC7"            '$G15
End Sub
```

Translated to your locale Zeile/Spalte `Z1S1`:

```
Public Sub Test()
 a = 15
 Cells(a, 8).FormulaR1C1Local = "=Z(" & a & ")S7" '$G30
 Cells(a, 8).FormulaR1C1Local = "=Z" & a & "S7"   '$G$15
 Cells(a, 8).FormulaR1C1Local = "=ZS7"            '$G15
End Sub
```

Comment: I did not know that, great answer! Thanks.